# limit SHACL class to one of the specific types and nothing else

Tags: logic, rdf, shacl

Suppose I have data like:

```
<http://domain/mySubj> abc:someProperty <http://domain/myObj>.
<http://domain/myObj> a <http://domain/Type1>.
<http://domain/myObj> a <http://domain/Type2>.
<http://domain/myObj> a <http://domain/WrongType>.
```

I want to write a SHACL rule that raise a violation if myObj has any type other that Type1 and Type2.

I have tried to write it like

```
sh:property [
      a sh:PropertyShape ;
      sh:path abc:someProperty ;
      sh:or   (
                   [ sh:class <http://domain/Type1> ; ]
                   [ sh:class <http://domain/Type2> ; ]
               ) ;
     ...
```

But this will not raise a violation since `sh:or` will pass as soon as one of the tests are correct. I can't also use `sh:xone` since this will need only one of Type1 and Type2 and not both, to be present. Even if I try to say `sh:or`([`sh:xone` (type1 type2)] [`sh:and` (type1 type2)]) my test will not produce the correct result since the `and` test will pass because we have type1 and type2 present and don't care about the Wrongtype.

Is there a way that I can say the class should be one or more things from a specific set of things and not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about direct rdf:types only, I believe you can solve this using sh:in on the rdf:type of the values:

```
sh:property [
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path abc:someProperty ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path rdf:type ;
        sh:in ( abc:Type1 abc:Type2 ) ;
    ] ;
]
```

Comment: I have tried this and this seems to have the same problem. That is, for the example mentioned above, when the correct type is present the sh:in check will not raise violation for the wrong type.

Comment: This actually works if I don't nest the property! So I have tried it like: sh:property[
               a sh:PropertyShape ;
               sh:path (abc:someProperty rdf:type); 
               sh:in ( abc:Type1 abc:Type2 ) ]; and it is working fine. Thank you so much!